# How to create regex dynamically in dart

Tags: dart

I have a regex expression that I'm trying to create dynamically.

```
RegExp reg4 = RegExp(r'(two+\s\w+\s+one)');
```

My intention is to replace the value at two to be set dynamically

I've tried this

```
  var two = "two";
  
  RegExp reg4 = RegExp(r'(' + two + '+\s\w+\s+one)');
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `r` on the second part of the string:

```dart
var two = "two";
RegExp reg4 = RegExp(r'(' + two + r'+\s\w+\s+one)');
//                                ^ <- that one!
```

Without that `r`, the `\s`s and `\w` in the second string are interpreted as *string* escapes, and disappear before they get to the `RegExp` parser.

I'll also point out that the result of `(two+\s\w+\s+one)` has a `+` applying to only the `o` of `two`.
You might want to create `((?:two)+\s\w+\s+one)` instead, so you repeat the entire "two" string.

Another thing to consider is whether you want to match the `two` variable's string verbatim, or if it can contain a RegExp too.
If you want it verbatim, so that a value of `var two = "[NOTE]";` won't match a single character, the string should be escaped:

```dart
RegExp reg4 = RegExp(r'((?:' + RegExp.escape(two) + r')+\s\w\s+one)');
```